# Which Google Cloud products do I need for my use case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine, websocket, google-cloud-platform, vonage

I wish to route a phone call to an ASP.NET MVC web app that is hosted on a server, and then open a web socket to gain access to the call's audio. I am not concerned about how to access the audio or process it etc. All I am needing help with is hosting a web app and opening an accessible web socket.

I have tried app engine, but with little success as I couldn't manage to open a web socket... I was able to get everything working with Azure services, however, I would like to transfer my web app to Google's services.

Can I stil use app engine to host the ASP.NET MVC app? If so, how can I open a websocket?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can host ASP.NET apps in [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/) but can't use [websockets YET](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348#comment231).

As for comment 231, it seems that its release in Flexible environment is likely in the not so distant future.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with Google App Engine. However, you can always use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), which is essentially a VM in Google's network that you can configure as your own webserver and you have virtually full control of its connectivity and ports.

Comment: How would I go about configuring it as a web server?

Comment: Compute Engine is essentially just a VM, so you can configure it as you would your own home server (except it's on the Google Cloud). You can open up ports, have an external static IP and install Apache or other software...