# Python using the correct socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, google-app-engine, websocket

I am using Google Cloud and Google App Engine, and I want to have one of our service API's to use `socket` connection instead of a regular HTTP connection where a request is received and a response is sent once per query.

I need this socket connection so that there will be a constant connection and stream of current data being sent back to the user whenever it is updated.

I have read several documents and the Google App Engine docs for sockets suggests using the socket library. But at the bottom of the docs, they provide a sample app that uses Google App Engine with sockets, but the socket in the example app is made from `nntplib` and not `socket`. How many python libraries are there where a socket can be made / used of and which socket should I be using for this kind of connection.

It says in python docs `nntplib` is used for implementing a news reader or poster, so I am unsure if this is the correct socket connection type I should be using for sending back current data of users online to users on the front end.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/nntplib.html

Should I just use

`socket.socket()`

EDIT:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#making_httplib_use_sockets

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the type of connection you need, [Websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) would be a good idea so you can create a full-duplex communication channel. However Google App Engine (GAE) doesn’t have support for Websockets yet. As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151731/8456296) it will be implemented soon for GAE Flexible.

There's a Feature Request for Websockets in GAE, you can track the updates in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/35886348)

In the meanwhile if you need Websockets you have to use a [Compute Engine instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)

Regarding the support for Sockets in GAE, you can use any library that import socket (poplib, nntplib etc) that don’t violate some limitations and restrictions listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that sockets are not well supported either but I I came across the sockets python API doc, which I have now put in my OP. So according to that document, it says sockets can be used but are limited to "outbound connections" only. Not sure if this is what I need to send out real time updates of users online statuses.

Comment: @HenryLee Outbound connections means that your app will have to start the socket connection. Normally, to do what you want, you would have to create a listening socket (inbound) to where your clients will connect to, and then send to them the data. That way, I don't think you'll be able to achieve that by using sockets in GAE.

Comment: Okay @dhauptman, so would that mean I could just create a "Client Side" socket? I have an API/URL from a third party service that is already a Websocket connection `(https://www.thirdPartyURL.com //This is their websocket ip)`. Would you know if I could just use the Python socket to connect to this IP and subscribe to it? Since this URL is already a websocket, I am thinking I dont need to create my own socket server but just create a client side socket to subscribe to this one? This URL returns users online status. How can I get real time updates from this Websocket with GAE webApp2?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if the websocket will be able to upgrade the socket connetion to a websocket one. If can consider different approaches you can take a look at the [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) approach that works only from server to client, more close to what you need, different from the bidirectional channel on websockets. There's a good [article](https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b) about this that you may take a look.

Comment: If you are fine with yet another different approach, you may consider using [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/).

Answer (score 0):

My original intentions were to not use any additional services or fees such as the many great ones suggest by @dhauptman, but it seems like according to the Google App Engine docs for sockets (Python 2.7): 
[Python Sockets Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations-and-restrictions)

it seems like since sockets only support outbound sockets, I can either just create a socket connection with subscribed events and whenever an event occurs and updates, just query the API for a task handler and send it back as a response.

Another option would be to use httplib library instead of Google App Engines urlfetch. When using the httplib library, it can be configured to use a socket connection in the app.yaml file. This will overcome the problem of reaching urlfetch limits.